# Navigation Vertical Sliding menu

Tags: jquery, asp.net, css

In My website, I want a vertical slide menu which slide up and down  and also fit/fade in/out when sliding.

**[Example](http://www.thebullittagency.com/)** - (center vertical slider menu) I am new to jquery and dont know steps to achive this.

Please help me to achive this.

Comment: if you want to achieve this, then you have to use .trigger(). By this you have to trigger the down/up arrow on keypress.

Answer (score 0):

this is a simple  tutorial which tells you how to create  a vertical slider from scratch

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/build-a-simple-jquery-news-ticker--net-6331

you may need to tune it a bit for adding `fade-in` and `fade-out` effect .

Happy Coding :)